# How to prevent jQuery mouseenter/mouseleave events upon click

Tags: jquery

I have a feeling I may be going about this completely the wrong way... Hopefully someone can help me.

I have developed a star ratings system for my application.

Below is the code I have so far which does the following:

A single star is displayed with a number inside it which is retrieved from the database via JSON.  When you hover over this single star the 10 stars fadeIn.  When you click on this it then initialises 'voting' mode and mouseenter, mouseleave event handlers are asigned to the individual stars.  When you then click a star an ajax post is made which updates the database, replaces the number (of average vote score) in the numbered star and add's a class to the relevent number of stars so that there is a visual representation of the star rating for this item.  This all works fine.

The problem:-

Currently when you have clicked once to enter 'vote' mode then hovered over the stars (which adds highlight classes as you mouseenter) then clicked to actually vote the original mouseenter/mouseleave event handlers are still live on the individual stars.

I would like the adding/removing of classes upon hovering to stop once the user has voted.

I'm certain the answer will be something to do with either using event.stopPropagation of by unbinding the the handlers themselves with .off() but I cannot seem to make it work.

Any ideas?

```
//show ratings on hover
$('#full-width-layout_c1_col-1-1_1').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', 
                                        '.rate', 
                                        function (e) {

  $ratings = $(this).parent().find('.ratings_stars');

  if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
    $ratings.fadeIn();
  }

  if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
    $ratings.fadeOut();
  }

  if (e.type == 'click') {

    $('#full-width-layout_c1_col-1-1_1').on('mouseenter mouseleave click',
                                            '.ratings_stars', 
                                            function (e) {

      var $vote = $(this).parent().find('.vote_info').text();
      var $hover = $(this).prevAll().andSelf();
      var $original = $(this).parent()
                             .find('.star_' + $vote)
                             .prevAll()
                             .andSelf();

      if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $hover.addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
      }

      if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {
        $hover.andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
        $original.addClass('ratings_vote');
      }

      //Highlight stars on hover and insert into database on click
      if (e.type == 'click') {

        var $row = $(this).closest('tr').find('.songnamecolumn');
        var $rating = $(this).index() + 1;
        var $songID = $(this).closest('tr')
                             .find('.songnamecolumn')
                             .attr('alt');

        var $userID = $('#loggedin_user_id').text();

        $.ajax({
          url: "/wp-content/ratings.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'song_id=' 
                + $songID 
                + '&user_id=' 
                + $userID 
                + '&rating=' 
                + $rating,
          success: function () {
            $songid = $songID;

            updateRating($songid, $row, $original);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The relevant HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="rate">
    <div class="star_1 ratings_stars ratings_vote" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_2 ratings_stars ratings_vote" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_3 ratings_stars ratings_vote" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_4 ratings_stars ratings_vote" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_5 ratings_stars ratings_vote" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_6 ratings_stars" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_7 ratings_stars" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_8 ratings_stars" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_9 ratings_stars" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="star_10 ratings_stars" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="vote_info">
        5
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like? I'm sure there's a way to simplify this, but need to look at the markup

Comment: I've added some example HTML for my ratings system. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly, I have found a solution already.  Although hopefully someone else can offer a more elegant one.

I simply set the ajax onsuccess function to add a class of 'voted' to the parent element and used a standard if/else to check against the parent element having a class of 'voted' and using return false; if it does, else... bind the mouseenter/mouseleave/click functions.

Feels like a bit of a hack to me and i'm certain there must be a better way.

I'll leave it a while before marking this as answered in case someone can give me a better solution.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Id as the selector you could also use this.off('mouseenter');

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/off/

I've found that it does not necessarily work if you are using a more generic selector unless you also use the second parameter which is the exact selector used in the .on() command.

But if you will always be using the unique Id as the selector, this should work. See the documentation link.

I'm voting up your answer because that solution works even with a more generic selector.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this was the first thing I tried and seemed to have no effect.  The more I think about it adding a 'voted' class will have other benefits which could be useful anyway. I suppose I can now offer better user feedback depending upon this class. i.e. dynamically generating tooltips with different content dependant upon class... 'voted' class gives the user "click to change your vote" rather than "click to vote" etc.  I suppose I could even go further and add a booleon into my server side code and check against the logged in user applying the 'voted' class automatically.